# Summarizing an array into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, function, dplyr

I wonder how to turn my `TABLE` below to my `Desired_output`?

In my `Desired_output`, `n_study` is the number of rows in `TABLE` for which the value corresponding to a column other than `study` is **NOT 0**.

For example, for the first element in `TABLE` (`, , treat_grp = conventional`), `n_study` for `baseline` is `1` because there is only 1 row for `baseline` with a non 0 element, and so on.

Also, in my `Desired_output`, `sum` is simply the column sum of each element of `TABLE`.

Is my `Desired_output` possible in R?

(*I tried `addmargins(TABLE) %>% as.data.frame.array()` without success*)

```
DATA <- structure(list(study = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
       4, 5, 5), time = c("baseline", "posttest1", "posttest2", "baseline", 
       "posttest1", "posttest2", "posttest1", "posttest1", "posttest1", 
        "posttest1", "posttest1", "posttest1", "posttest1", "posttest1", 
         "posttest2"), treat_grp = c("conventional", "conventional", "conventional", 
           "conventional", "conventional", "conventional", "conventional", 
            "framework_notes", "conventional", "conventional", "conventional", 
             "conventional", "conventional", "vocabulary_notebook", "vocabulary_notebook"
               )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

TABLE <- table(DATA)

Desired_output <- read.table(header=T,text="
n_study     time      treat_grp       sum
  1     baseline   conventional         2
  4     posttest1  conventional         8
  1     posttest2  conventional         2
  0     baseline   framework_notes      0
  1     posttest1  framework_notes      1
  0     posttest2  framework_notes      0
  0     baseline   vocabulary_notebook  0
  1     posttest1  vocabulary_notebook  1
  1     posttest2  vocabulary_notebook  1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
data.frame(table(DATA))|>
  aggregate(cbind(n_study = Freq > 0, sum = Freq) ~ time + treat_grp, sum)

       time           treat_grp n_study sum
1  baseline        conventional       1   2
2 posttest1        conventional       4   8
3 posttest2        conventional       1   2
4  baseline     framework_notes       0   0
5 posttest1     framework_notes       1   1
6 posttest2     framework_notes       0   0
7  baseline vocabulary_notebook       0   0
8 posttest1 vocabulary_notebook       1   1
9 posttest2 vocabulary_notebook       1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA |>
  count(study, time, treat_grp) |>
  summarize(n_study = n(),
            sum = sum(n),
            .by = c(time, treat_grp)) |>
  complete(time, treat_grp, fill = list(n_study = 0, sum = 0))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  time      treat_grp           n_study   sum
  <chr>     <chr>                 <int> <int>
1 baseline  conventional              1     2
2 baseline  framework_notes           0     0
3 baseline  vocabulary_notebook       0     0
4 posttest1 conventional              4     8
5 posttest1 framework_notes           1     1
6 posttest1 vocabulary_notebook       1     1
7 posttest2 conventional              1     2
8 posttest2 framework_notes           0     0
9 posttest2 vocabulary_notebook       1     1
```

Comment: Also, your last line `complete(time, treat_grp, fill = list(n_study = 0, sum = 0))` throws an error saying: `Caused by error in `grid_dots()`:
! '..1' must be a vector, not a function.`

Comment: @SimonHarmel use `..group_by(time, treat_grp) %>%summarise(n_study = n(), sum = sum(n))%>%...`

Comment: @Onyambu, yes I did that but still the last line `complete(time, treat_grp, fill = list(n_study = 0, sum = 0))` throws an error saying: `Problem while computing '..1 = complete(data = dplyr::cur_data(), ..., fill = fill,
  explicit = explicit)'. Caused by error in 'grid_dots()':
! '..1' must be a vector, not a function.`

Comment: @SimonHarmel I can only help with a base R code to do the same. Usually the packages are different versions etc, so mostly help with base R. I do not know why you are getting that error though. If you wish for a base R olution et me know

Comment: @Onyambu, I will appreciate the base R solution? I also found the error explanation in the documentation: `With grouped data frames, 'complete()' operates within each group. Because of this, you cannot complete a grouping column.` So, data before `complete()` must be ungrouped.

Comment: @SimonHarmel then the code should work if you use `ungroup` before calling `complete`